# Array of pointers to structs

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct, aggregation

EDIT: Im quite new to c++ and programming as a whole.

I'm supposed to make a program where i use stucts and and an array of structs.

> Security council < > Member of Security council

My task was to use the concept of "UML aggregation" to create a program where I use structs and struct arrays. (I hope you understand what I'm trying to say)

Since a Member of a Security council is a part of a Security council, and not the other way around, the struct of Security council must have an array of its members.(bear with me)

```
//example
struct Member_sc{
    char * name;
    int age;
};
struct Security_council{
    Member_sc members[10];    
};
```

Now, I've created this program and everything works perfectly (according to my teacher), but now she told me create an exact copy, but instead of the "members" array I must use an array of pointers to the Member_sc structs. Since I havent completely figured out how pointers work, I have come across some problems.

I can post the code to the original program if needed, but it contains 4 files(main, header, and some function files) and it would be a pain to try and post it here.

here is the prototype (all in one file, for now)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct member_sc{
    string name;
};

struct security_council{
    member_sc *point;
    security_council **search; // ignore this for now
    int n;
    security_council():n(0){}
};

void in_mem( member_sc &x){
    getline(cin,x.name);
}
void out_mem(member_sc &x){
    cout<<x.name<<endl;
}
void in_SC(security_council &q, member_sc &x){ 
    int num; //number of members
    cin>>num;
    for(int i=0; i<num; ++i){
        in_mem(x);
        q.point[q.n]=x;
        q.n++;
        }
}
void out_SC(security_council &q,member_sc &x){
    for(int i=0; i<q.n; ++i){
        out_mem(q.point[i]);
    }
}
int main(){

    member_sc y;
    security_council x;
    in_mem(y);              // works
    out_mem(y);             // works
    in_SC(x,y);             // crashes after i input the number of members i want
    out_SC(x,y);            // 

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The program crashes after you input the number of members you want in your Security council.
Is my way of thinking right? or should I use dynamic memory allocation?

in addition to that (my teacher gave me an additional task) create a search function using pointers. i thought that pointer to pointer may be good for that, but im not sure.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.
( i think ill figure out the search thingy once i figure out how pointers to structs work)

Comment: Do you know `vector`?

Comment: You never initialize the memory that the `point` member refers to, yet then in statement `q.point[q.n]=x;` you attempt to use it.

Comment: @deviantfan sorry, but no

Comment: Basically, after you read in the number of members, and before the `for` loop where you read in the individual members, you need to **allocate** an array of an appropriate number of `member_sc` objects and store it in `q.point`. Don't forget to free this memory when done using it.

Comment: Once you do that, you can also remove the `member_sc &x` argument from both `in_SC` and `out_SC`, as that will become unnecessary. Furthermore, some validation of your input seems to be in place. Consider what will happen if the user enters a negative number, and you attempt to use that directly to determine the size of memory to allocate.

Comment: @DanMašek THANK YOU so much. it finally works :D.

Comment: @DanMašek I tried using `delete [ ] q.point` but it dosnt seem to work.. :(

Comment: @Muhammedbakijev Please post the latest revision of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your issue is this:

```
cin >> num;
```

this reads only the digits that have been typed and stops at the newline. Then, in `in_mem` the call to `getline` immediately reads a newline. You need to do:

```
cin >> num;
cin.ignore();
```

this will drain the input stream of any remaining input, or catch up so to speak.

However your core problem is that you don't allocate any memory for "`point`" to point to.

A pointer is just a variable holding a value that happens to be the address (offset from 0) of a thing in memory. If you are going to the airport and write "Gate 23" on a post-it note, the post it note is a pointer and "Gate 23" is the value.

In your code, that variable is uninitialized and will either be 0, if you are lucky, or some random address in memory if you aren't so lucky.

To the airport analogy: you arrive at the airport and find that your post-it note has "pizza" written on it. Not helpful.

Your teacher has actually specified an "array of pointers". Break that down: pointer to what? `member_sc`, that's `member_sc*`. And now make it an array

```
member_sc* pointers[10];
```

NOTE: This is not good, modern C++ - in modern C++ you would use something called a smart pointer (std::unique_ptr) probably.

```
std::unique_ptr<member_sc[]> pointers(new member_sc[10]);
```

Now you have 10 pointers instead of just one, and all of them will need some allocation to point to. The easiest way to do this is with the `new` keyword and the copy constructor:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    in_mem(x);
    pointers[q.n] = new member_sc(x);  // make a clone of x
    q.n++;
}
```

or in modern C++

```
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    in_mem(x);  // x is temporary for reading in
    pointers[q.n] = std::make_unique<member_sc>(x);
    q.n++;
}
```

However there is a limitation with this approach: you can only have upto 10 security council members. How do you work around this? Well, the modern C++ answer would be to use a `std::vector`

```
std::vector<member_sc> members;
// ditch n - vector tracks it for you.

// ...

for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
    in_mem(x);
    q.members.push_back(x);
    // q.n is replaced with q.members.size()
    // which is tracked automatically for you
}
```

but I'm guessing your teacher wants you to actually understand pointers before you get to forget about them with modern luxuries.

We need to re-use the pointer stuff we've just used above and change "pointers" to an array of pointers.

Which means we're going to want a pointer to a set of pointer-to-member_sc.

```
member_sc** pointers;
```

We'll need to assign some memory for this to point to:

```
cin >> num;
cin.ignore();
if (num == 0) {
    // do something
    return;
}
pointers = new member_sc[num];
```

luckily, using a pointer to an array is as easy as using an array, the only major difference being that you lose the size-of-array information -- all you have is the address, not the dimensions.

```
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    in_mem(x);
    q.pointers[i] = new member_sc(x);
    q.n++;
}
```

I'm deliberately not providing you with a complete working example because this is obviously for a class.

Comment: Let me add: pointers are easy, but learning pointers is *hard*. Don't be afraid to talk to your teacher about any confusion you have with pointers, they will absolutely understand.

Comment: Ill have a go and see what i can manage to do. Thank you very much :D

Comment: IMHO `member_sc** pointers = new member_sc[num];` is incorrect. You create an array of *num* `member_sc` structures, and try to assign it to a an array of pointers to `member_sc` structures.

Comment: @kfsone When i try to deallocate the memory it dosnt work for some reason. im using `delete[] q.pointers` at the end of my code in main.cpp, but when i check with `sizeof()` the size stays the same and it will still output the data even after the deallocation...

Comment: with dynamic allocation, you lose automatic size information, sizeof() is only going to tell you the size of the pointer. All `delete[]` does is return the memory to the system for subsequent re-use, it doesn't zero it out. So being able to still see the data after allocation - for some period of time - is not unusual but not something you should take advantage of.

Comment: But +1 for using `delete[]` :)

Answer (score 1):

You never initialize the memory that the point member refers to, yet then in statement `q.point[q.n]=x;` you attempt to use it.

Basically, after you read in the number of members, and before the for loop where you read in the individual members, you need to allocate an array of an appropriate number of `member_sc` objects and store it in `q.point`. Don't forget to free this memory when done using it.

Once you do that, you can also remove the `member_sc &x` argument from both `in_SC` and `out_SC`, as that will become unnecessary.

Finally, some validation of your input seems to be in place. Consider what will happen if the user enters a negative number, and you attempt to use that directly to determine the size of memory to allocate.

---

Here's a simple example showing how to use a dynamically allocated array of structures:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct member_sc {
    std::string name;
};

void test_array(int count)
{
    if (count <= 0) {
        return; // Error
    }

    // Allocate an array of appropriate size
    member_sc* members = new member_sc[count];
    if (members == nullptr) {
        return; // Error
    }

    // ... fill in the individual array elements
    for(int i(0); i < count; ++i) {
        // ... read from input stream
        // I'll just generate some names to keep it simple
        members[i].name = "User A";
        members[i].name[5] += i; // Change the last character, so we have different names
    }

    // Now let's try printing out the members...
    for(int i(0); i < count; ++i) {
        std::cout << i << ": " << members[i].name << "\n";
    }

    delete[] members;   

}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    for(int count(1); count <= 10; ++count) {
        std::cout << "Test count=" << count << "\n";
        test_array(count);
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Example on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11f3c4beb433a2f1)

---

Of course, there are many other issues with this style of code, but I believe that's beside the point of this question. For example:

- Instead of using bare pointers, it would be more appropriate to use some kind of a smart pointer.
- Instead of a simple array, use some kind of collection, such as a vector.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asked to use an array of pointers, do so: replace

```
Member_sc members[10];
```

with

```
Member_sc* members[10];
```

Then fill out that array using dynamic memory allocation. As a matter of good form, at the end of the program remember to release the dynamic memory you have used.

Comment: The thing that i forgot to mention is that the array of pointers cannot have a predefined size.